# how to change screen brightness when entering background

Tags: objective-c

I have a 'low power' mode in my app that dims screen to 0 brightness. I'd like to restore the brightness when user backgrounds the app.  I am calling

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 1.0f;
```

in my UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification handler code, but it doesn't work. (my app doesn't have access to mainScreen at that moment anymore?)

is there a way to do this? I couldn't find anything that gives a WillEnterBackground effect.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try putting the code in applicationWillResignActive? I was having the same problem, and moved my code from applicationDidEnterBackground to applicationWillResignActive, and it switched the screen brightness before moving the app to the background.

Comment: You may add some links to the documentation to complete the answer.